# Passing Nested Dictionary to EMR via add_job_flow_steps

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, amazon-emr

I create a python dictionary called my_dict with some metadata. I convert my_dict to a string via `json.dumps()`. my_dict is then passed to EMR via `add_job_flow_steps` as args in HadoopJarStep.

Once the step has been submitted, the args look like the below in the Arguments section of the EMR step in the UI:

```
--my_dict "{\"level_one_key\": {\"level_two_key\": \"level_two_value\"}}"
```

Now, I also pass EMR a python file to run called `execute.py`. The above arguments are passed into `execute.py`'s main function, where it is immediately converted into a dictionary with `json.loads()`. It looks like:

`parser.add_argument('--my_dict', type=json.loads, required=False)`

***The problem:*** when I pass a nested dictionary, the step fails 20 seconds in with UNKOWN ERROR as the reason and no logs written whatsoever. :(

However when I pass it as a flat dictionary, like:

```
--my_dict "{\"level_one_key\": \"level_one_value\"}"
```

It works just fine.

I don't want to post too much of my code, because this is work related. But am I missing something? I feel like I should be able to pass a nested dictionary no problem. I have also tried converting the dictionary after it's been passed to main, like this:

```
parser.add_argument('--my_dict', type=str, required=False)

my_dict = json.loads(args.my_dict)
```

Yet it still fails. Any ideas?

***Update:*** when the nested dictionary is printed out after parsing as a str (as opposed to using json.loads) in execute.py, it looks like:

```
{"level_one_key": {"level_two_key": "level_two_value"
```

It's missing the last two brackets of the dictionary... for whatever reason. Obviously, this is causing the error, but I don't know why it's not passing the entire dictionary into main.

Comment: Can you print your dictionary out after you parse it and make sure it gets parsed correctly?

Comment: @KyleParsons - I added the print out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding another key value pair to the end of the dictionary that is not nested. Like this:

```
--my_arg "{\"level_one_key\": {\"level_two_key\": \"level_two_value\"}, \"level_one_second_key\": \"level_one_second_value\"}"
```